# How to edit configmap configuration in spring boot kubernetes application during runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, configmap

We have application with huge configuration (this is just a part):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-app
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    config:
      app: MY-APP
      my-custom-map:
        KEY1: value1
        KEY2: value2
        KEY3: value3
        KEY4: value4
      something1: true
      something2: 123
      something3: string123
      something4: null
      subclass:
        anotherMap:
          "[AAA:0.0.1,BBB:CCC]": "DDD:EEEE"
      subclass2:
        something4: AAAA
        anotherMap2:
          0.0.3: 0.0.3
```

I follow [this](https://github.com/fabric8io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/tree/master/spring-cloud-kubernetes-examples/kubernetes-reload-example) example to bind configmap with spring boot configuration but there is still some problem for example how to solve null in yaml which spring yaml postprocessor resolve as empty string: [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19986)

second problem is how to handle this configmap. I know I can edit and then use apply but this can lead to some error. Is there some tool which I can use to edit this yaml and make some bash script for editing ? like: ./my-script.sh -function addMyCustomMapValue -args "KEY5:value5" . I tried to explore [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) but I think there is some limitation and it is hard to use for some use-case and then [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) which I think is good for creating configmap but not for editing existing one.

Is there already some good example for this use-case ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option : 1**

You can Use the Lens : https://k8slens.dev/kubernetes.html

It's UI for monitoring and Managing K8s clusters. Using this you can also edit the configmap.

**Option : 2**

You can manage all the Key value into single YAML file and create configmap from file :

```
kubectl create configmap some-config \
  --from-file=some-key=some-config.yaml \
  -n some-namespace \
  -o yaml \
  --dry-run | kubectl apply -f -
```

**Option : 3**

Use `helm` and `values.yaml` template to create and your chart and apply it further.

**Configmap** using **YAML** helm

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: jksconfig
data:
  config.json: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "config.json" | indent 4 }}
```

**Option : 4**

If you are using the configmap as Environment or injecting it to file path you can use the Hashi corp vault also : https://www.vaultproject.io/

**Option : 5**

As you suggested you can create one **Bash** script which will export the existing running **Configmap** to a new **YAML** file one you are done with editing YAML manually. You can apply the changes to **K8s** cluster.

```
#bin/bash
kubectl get configmap <configmap-name>  -o yaml > cofig.yaml
```

You can also check the : https://github.com/Gallore/yaml_cli might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: application-conf
data: 
  {{- if .Values.global.applicationConfiguration }}
  application.properties: | 
    {{- .Values.global.applicationConfiguration  | nindent 4 }}
   {{- end }}
```

This is how we can specify a config map. Add `applicationConfiguration` in your values.yaml if it specified then only it will write an `application.properties` externally. It need not have all the properties.

Answer (score 2):

This is best tool to edit and make changes in kubernetes env

k9s : https://github.com/derailed/k9s

You can explore https://kubeval.instrumenta.dev/ to catch any configmap error before deploying

Comment: How do you know that it is the best tool?